# Redirecting to https and subfolder .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

Situation: afwezigheden.eu is the main domain with a few coupled domains (= aliases?) like skatespots.be, inviteme.eu, halftwaalf.be... Now I'm trying to redirect those aliasses to a subfolder, without the users seeing it.
Al those sites are in a subfolder _DOMAINNAME. For example: skatespots.be is in afwezigheden.eu/_skatespots

Also I have an SSL certificate, so I would like to redirect all domains to https too.

I tried several things, the last one is this one, where skatespots seems to work and everything is redirected over https.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_skatespots/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?skatespots\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /_skatespots/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_halftwaalf/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?halftwaalf\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /_halftwaalf/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_inviteme/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?inviteme\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /_inviteme/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What if you put the folder structure as this:

afwezigheden.eu/sites/skatespots.eu
afwezigheden.eu/sites/halftwaalf.eu

And then use this in your afwezigheden.eu/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sites/
RewriteRule (.*) /sites/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't have access to my server right now. I'll test it out in the late afternoon, but your solution seems reasonable :-)

Comment: I'm morge looking for a transparant "redirect", so that inviteme.eu/page doesn't go to afwezigheden.eu/_inviteme/page

Comment: But then you shouldn't use htaccess. Set up proper virtual hosts instead.

Comment: Can't it be done with htaccess? My host doesn't has cpanel, but a simple version of their own panel...

Comment: htaccess is for rules in the current site. What you are looking for are the virtualhosts in the apache config. Maybe change the host if they don't support anything?

Comment: Allright. Thanks. But I'm pretty sure I once did this with htaccess... :)

Comment: My domains aren't linked to the domain anymore, so I can't test it out without having a few hours of downtime. Nevertheless: thanks!